# use python requests to send post request: Content-Type=multipart/form-data;

Tags: python, http, python-requests

request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarygwvtBWIEYsiYIdsp

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sourceZoneId"

10

------WebKitFormBoundarygwvtBWIEYsiYIdsp

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="targetZoneId"

11

------WebKitFormBoundarygwvtBWIEYsiYIdsp

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

test upload



------WebKitFormBoundarygwvtBWIEYsiYIdsp

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0]"; filename="github.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain



------WebKitFormBoundarygwvtBWIEYsiYIdsp--
```

I send the POST request like this:

```
headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygwvtBWIEYsiYIdsp','Accept':'*/*','x-auth-token':token}

files = {'sourceZoneId':'10',
               'targetZoneId':'11',
               'description':'test upload',
               'file[0]':('github.txt',open('E:\chenyao\github.txt','rb'),'text/plain')}

requests.post(url,header = headers, files = files)
```

but return HTTP 400 Bad Request. Who knows why? Thanks！

Comment: Try to send without specifying `headers`

Comment: send without specifying headers is OK! Thank you very much！